# Tag still running in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[image: debugger]
I'm facing problems with GTM , ' the still running problem ' to be precise.
I know this is a known issue in GTM , as it is caused by using GA variable in the GA-CODE box or vice versa.
But in my case, it should have been done correctly (see screenshots)..
Are there other things that cause tags to hang ?

I tried both ways : Using a GA Variable and removing it and using the override settings box and filling in the UA-######-1 code..

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Simo ,

the problem was a not existing Optimize ID in another tag!
Very strange that this blocks some other tags that have nothing to do with it , but it did fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is an unfortunate "feature", but if you try to load a Google Optimize container that doesn't respond (due to not existing or due to not being active), the container returns a 404 status error, but the `ga()` queue keeps on trying to load it.

This means that **all** subsequent `ga()` calls are put on hold while the queue tries to load the Optimize container. Since there's no timeout for this, all Google Analytics calls that follow the Optimize `require` command will fail to fire, and GTM will show "Still running" for these hits.

I have reported this as a bug.